# Why does the energy of an atomic orbital depend on the proximity to charges?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

I was recently reading about [Crystal field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_field_theory) and especially crystal field splitting in the context of transition metals in coordination complexes. Here is what I think I have understood – or what at least makes sense to me:

When we have a transition metal, its $d$ orbitals are partly filled. If the metal is the center of an octahedral complex, we have six ligands (which each are positively charged) around the atom. The partly filled $d$ orbitals have different "shapes":

[image]

<sup>([Source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:D_orbitals.png))</sup>

Some of the orbitals kind of "lie" on the axes on which the ligands are, namely the $d_{z^2}$ and $d_{x^2-y^2}$ orbitals. Since these orbitals are closer to the positive charges of the ligands, their energy increases. Depending on the ligand, a low-spin complex can form which means that first the "lower energy" $d$-orbitals are completely filled. Apparently, this somehow also causes coordination complexes to often be colorful.

So far, so good (I think). What I am confused about is *why* exactly the orbitals "get" a higher energy level when closer to the ligands. I haven't been able to find any explanation. It would be great if someone could provide one that could be understandable by a high school student – i.e. either something "intuitive" (if this is possible) or not too complicated math, though I am willing to understand it if necessary.

Comment: Coulombic repulsion between the electron clouds of the ligands and of the $d_{z^2}$ orbital,  and of the $d_{x^2-y^2}$ orbitals is higher than between the ligands and the three other types of $d$ orbitals, due to electron density orientation. This causes an energy level difference between the former and the latter type of $d$ orbitals. The differences are small and electronic transitions between these levels are in the VIS range. That explains why so many D-block complexes are intensely coloured.

Comment: Atomic orbitals arise from the proximity of an electron to a nucleus, each of which is charged. Of course, other proximate charges will impact the orbitals.

Comment: @JonCuster thanks, this is the type of "intuitive" explanation I was looking for. You might want to consider expanding your comment into an answer